# Point spectrum of weighted shift operator on function space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the space $C_{0}[0,\infty)$ and the operator $(Tf)(t)=\lambda f(t+a)$ where $a,\lambda>1$. I’m trying to find the point spectrum of $T$, and by definition I need to find values of $w$ For which $$T-wI \qquad (1)$$ is not one to one.

I know that $g(t)= e^{\beta t}$ is an eigenfunction of $T$ where $Re(\beta)<0$ (so that $g$ remains in $C_0$) with eigenvalue $\lambda e^{\beta a}$ since $Tg=\lambda e^{\beta(t+a)}$.

In sequence spaces the idea seems straight forward for finding the point spectrum of shift operators however for function spaces it I’m having difficulty applying the definition and using (1) to find such $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ \lambda f(t+a)=w f(t)\ $ for all $\ t\ge 0\ $, and $\ f(0)\ne 0\ $, then taking $\ t\in [0,a)\ $,   we get $\ f(t+a) = \frac{w}{\lambda} f(t)\ $, and then $\ f(t+na) = 
\left(\frac{w}{\lambda}\right)^n f(t)\ $ for $\ n=2,3,\dots $, by induction.  For $\ f\ $ to belong to $\ C_0[0,\infty)\ $ we require  $\ \left\vert w\right\vert<\lambda\ $.

Conversely, if  $\ \left\vert w\right\vert<\lambda\ $, and $\ g\ $ is *any* continuous function on $\ [0, a]\ $ with $\ g(0)\ne0\ $, and $\ g(a)= \frac{w}{\lambda }g(0)\ $, and is extended to $\ [0,\infty)\ $ by putting $\ g(t+na)= \left(\frac{w}{\lambda}\right)^ng(t)\ $ for all $\ t\in [0,a)\ $ and $\ n=1,2,\dots\ $, then $\ g\in C_0[0,\infty)\ $, $\lambda g(t+a)=w g(t)\ $, for all $\ t\ge0\ $, so $\ g\ $ is an eigenfunction of $\ T\ $ with eigenvalue $\ w\ $, and $\ w\ $ is in the point spectrum of $\ T\ $.

On the other hand, if $\ \left\vert w\right\vert\ge \lambda\ $ and $\ \lambda f(t+a)=w f(t)\ $, with $\ f\in C_0[0,\infty)\ $, then by the same argument as above, we have $\ \left\vert f(t)\right\vert\ = \left\vert \left(\frac{\lambda}{w}\right)^nf(t+na)\right\vert\ \le \left\vert f(t+na)\right\vert\ $, for $\ t\in[0,\infty)\ $ (not just $\ t\in[0,a)\ $), and $\ n=1,2, \dots\ $.  Since $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}f(t+na)=0\ $, it follows that $\ f(t)=0\ $ for all $\ t\in[0,\infty)\ $.  So $\ T-wI\ $ is one to one, and $\ w\ $ is not in the point spectrum of $\ T\ $.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was wondering if the restriction $\frac{|w|}{\lambda}<1$ was equivalent in your first direction. Wouldn't $f$ still be in $C_0[0,\infty)$ if $w=1/2$ since $\lambda>1$? Also for your second direction after you define $\ g(t+na)= \left(\frac{w}{\lambda}\right)^ng(t)\,$ and you extend to $[0,\infty)$ do you mean to shift the interval $[0,a)$ also for each $n$? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the condition I had initially placed on $\ w\ $ was obviously wrong.  I've now corrected it.  I'm not sure what you mean by "shift the interval $\ [0,a)$" in your second question.  If $\ g\ $ is defined on $\ [0,a]\ $, then the equation $\ g(t+na)= \left(\frac{w}{\lambda}\right)^ng(t)\ $, for $\ t\in [0,a)\ $ defines it on the interval $\ \left[n,(n+1)a\right)\ $, and as long as $\ g(a)= \frac{w}{\lambda }g(0)\ $ it will be unambiguously defined and continuous.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about unambiguously defining the function to the whole semi axis. Thanks for your time and input I appreciate it.

Comment: Although it's fairly obvious, I've now added an argument to show that the point spectrum is *precisely* the set of complex numbers in the open disc $\ \left\{ w\left\vert  \lambda>\lvert w\rvert\right.\right\}\ $